# Add vmtools to linux installer ISO

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Is there a way to add vmware tools to a linux installer (debian or redhat)?

Curious if I could create a linux ISO would already have vmtools installed. So when I boot the vm for the first time to the ISO to install the OS, the GUI installer will have vmtools in it and would automatically install vmtools with the OS install.

Obviously this would be different per distro, but just curious how I would go about doing this.

I could of course install vmtools after the OS is installed, but I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Depends on the distro. The tools are already included on the CentOS 7 DVD, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [VMware OSP](https://www.vmware.com/support/packages) versions of the tools or `open-vm-tools` for newer distributions.

In both cases, they can be deployed via your yum/apt package manager and could easily integrate into your installation workflow.